# xcodebuild fails, but building from Xcode succeeds

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to automate my build using xcodebuild.

However, my xcodebuild fails while building static libraries, complaining that it can't find headers that are part of dependency frameworks.

No problem to build from Xcode.

Why is the result of xcodebuild different from the one of Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might accidentally build the Xcode project instead of the Xcode Workspace from `xcodebuild`.

If this is the case, replace:

```
xcodebuild -project "<*yourProjectFile*>.xcodeproj"
```

with:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <*yourWorkspaceFile*>.xcworkspace
```

After fixing this I get the exact same results from Xcode and `xcodebuild`.

Comment: Exactly the issue I was having. Thanks. Rule of thumb: if you are using CocoaPods, you should be building the workspace, not the project.